# Oracle 11gR2 error while installing on RHEL6_x64

Tags: oracle

Whenever I attempt to install Oracle it gives me this error in the install wizard on the group configuration screen. I am using group oinstall and user oracle has also been created.

```
INS-30060] Check for group existence failed.
```

After this step, the installer fails.

Comment: Is the user oracle *in* the group oinstall?

Comment: yes the user `oracle` is a member of group `oinstall`

Comment: Did any of the output indicate where it might've left a log file?  `/tmp/OraInstall[DATETIME]` and `$ORACLE_HOME/oraInventory/logs` are both likely places to check

Comment: When you added user oracle to the group oinstall, did you logout and log back in or is it the same session. In other words, when you run the "groups" command in the session you are installing oracle under, does it return oinstall in the list? Also, is this before the Oracle Inventory install portion or after?